# Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column - Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, input, database-migration, laravel-5.8

I don't understand this, I alter my table to add these columns

```
Schema::table('clusters', function($table)
{

    $table->string('ssaEnabled',1)->default('0');
    $table->string('ssaBackendUrl')->default(NULL);
    $table->string('ssaPortalApiUrl')->default(NULL);

});
```

in my store() I have this

```
$cluster->ssaEnabled            = Input::get('ssaEnabled','0');
$cluster->ssaBackendUrl         = Input::get('ssaBackendUrl','');
$cluster->ssaPortalApiUrl       = Input::get('ssaPortalApiUrl','');

$cluster->save();
```

I kept getting

> prod.ERROR: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column "ssaBackendUrl" violates not-null constraint

Why ??

1. I set it to default null already
2. I also add a backup value in my `Input::get()` in the 2nd param as an empty string

## Any hints?

How can I stop that ?

Comment: I think you have to add the `nullable()` method to that columns to make them nullables. Try `$table->string('ssaBackendUrl')->nullable();`

Comment: I can add that, but it will work on a newly set up only. How do I make it work or catch it in the code so it will not crash on the existing set up ?

Comment: [Column modifiers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#column-modifiers)

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you mean, but if you create a migration that [modifies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#column-modifiers) those columns to nullable, you shouldn't have that problem anymore

Comment: But the client set up already that schema, how do we update only the constraint onto the existing schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a new migration

`php artisan make:migration add_nullable_to_ssaBackendUrl_column_on_clusters_table --table=clusters`

[Updating Column Attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#updating-column-attributes)

> The `change` method allows you to modify the type and attributes of
> existing columns.

```php
Schema::table('clusters', function($table)
{

    $table->string('ssaBackendUrl')->nullable()->change();

});
```

- Run the migration

`php artisan migrate`

Comment: Do I do it on exist migration or create a new migration file? pls advise.

Comment: @code8888 Create a new migration

Comment: better name `php artisan make:migration add__nullable_on_clusters_table --table=clusters `

Comment: @code8888 , Thanks for the suggestion. I've edited the migration name.